# Como enviar un fragmento binario al servidor mediante ajax

Tags: javascript, java

He creado un script que convierte un fichero en binario para dividir el array en fragmentos más pequeños y enviarlos al servidor.

Ahora mismo estoy enviando array al webservice, es la manera adecuada de enviarlo para poder descodificarlo despues en java o es mejor crear un **FormData** y añadir el contenido del array dentro ?

[image: webservice]

```js
var reader, file, slice_size = (1024**2)*5;
  
  $(document).on("click", "#dbi-file-upload-submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    file = $("#dbi-file-upload")[0].files[0];
    reader = new FileReader();
    
    submit_file(0);
  });
  
  function submit_file(start){
    let next_slice = start+slice_size;
    let blob = file.slice(start, next_slice);
    
    reader.onload = function(event){
      let unit8 = new Uint8Array(event.target.result);
      
      save_slice(unit8).done(function(res){
        let size_done = start + slice_size;
        let percent_done = Math.floor((size_done/file.size)*100);
        
        if(next_slice < file.size){
          $('#dbi-upload-progress').html(`Uploading File -  ${percent_done}%`);
          submit_file(next_slice);
        }else{
          $('#dbi-upload-progress').html(`Done !`);
        }
      });
      
    }
  
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  }
  
  function save_slice(slice){
    return $.ajax({
      url: '/Save.tstVideo',
      type: 'POST',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false, 
      data: slice
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input id="dbi-file-upload" type="file"/><br><br>
  <span id="dbi-upload-progress"></span>
  <input id="dbi-file-upload-submit" class="button button-primary" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: Por cuestiones de seguridad lo peor que puedes hacer es directamente enviar formato binario hacia un servidor, haz intentado subirlo como texto u obtener el archivo en `Base64`?, en `base64` el archivo pesa muchisimo mas, pero resulta ser muchisimo mas seguro.

Comment: `ArrayBuffer` es mejor opcion que directamente formato binario, pues son chunks de informacion, esta informacion no es directamente interpretable por la app, pero `Java` es algo jodido la verdad, cualquier cosa puede fallar, es complicado hacer que esto funcione bien en `Java` sin incurrir en problemas de seguridad y corrupcion de informacion.

Comment: @Riven antes de utilizar el ArrayBuffer estaba utilizando el Base64, pero me han sugerido utilizar el binario porque pesa menos y el base64 me daba problemas al decodificar.

Comment: si te daba problemas decodificar `base64` posiblemente fuese porque no tienes una configuracion de caracteres optima en Java.

Comment: Los archivos pequeños me los decodificaba bien, pero los videos decodificados no los podía reproducir.